# Equivalent option like openquery of SQL server in MySQL

Tags: mysql, command, equivalent, openquery

Is there similar kind of option like "OpenQuery" used in SQL server in MySQL.

Actually I need to operate the database residing in another server using MYSQL Command.

If there is any option, please let me know.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

See mysql command line options http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_host especially `--host`